# Switch to Virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv

If I installed packages globally like django, npm, etc., is it possible to switch to virtualenv on mac and install a different version on the virtual environment, or will follow the global installation?

Thanks!

Comment: "*…switch to virtualenv on mac and install a different version…*" This is exactly what virtual environments are for — to separate different sets of packages.

Comment: right...but will it work if i have a different version globally installed?

Comment: By default virtual environments separate packages even from the global set.